# Latex leaves left part of the page as blank. How can i fix this?

Tags: floats, page

At my last page, latex pushes my figure to the right side of the page and leaves whole left side as blank. Nothing like this happens for other pages. Why is this happening?
[image: blank page]

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a compilable example code which can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Btw your code is having many errors: Never ignore errors and please debug it until no errors left. Also, you should put `\includegraphics` to a `figure` environment and add a _real_ caption by `\caption` and a `\label` for a figure in your document, instead of putting to a `center` as well as inserting the caption really _manually_.

Comment: It is hard to help with no example provide, but note that the entire reason latex has figure environment is to allow figures to "float" ie be moved to avoid large gaps at page breaks, as you just have the `\includegraphics` directly in the main text if it does not fit at the bottom of one column there has to be a gap if it is moved to the next.

Comment: Welcome...hope you are searching the tag \cleardoublepage...If not so, please provide a MWE...

Comment: You might also be interested in using the `\caption` (or `\captionof` command if you don't want your figures to float) and a `\label`. This way, your figures are numbered automatically and you can easily refer to them using `\ref`.

Comment: the only error i have is "overful \hbox ...." is it related?